# TikZ only arrowhead is drawn, but not the arc itself

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, arc, angle

I tried to overlay an image with some drawings using the TkiZ-package and so far everything works but drawing arcs in the scope. Here only the arrowheads show but the arc itself is not. As you can see in the piture below the red arrowheads show at the desired positions, as well as all other lines and nodes.

Is there anything I am missing to properly draw the arcs representing angles?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{Medien/legdiagram.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \draw[ultra thick, fill=black] (0.225,0.636) circle (5pt) node[above=35] {BC} -- (0.425,0.636) circle (5pt) node[below=20] {CF} -- (0.66,0.735) circle (5pt) node[above=20] {FT} -- (0.78,0.08) circle (5pt) node[below=5] {F};
    \draw[ultra thick, dashed] (0.425,0.636) -- plot({0.425+0.26*cos(15+22.84)},{0.636+0.26*sin(15+22.84)})  -- (0.66,0.735);
    \draw[->,ultra thick,red,domain=22.84:37.84] -- plot({0.425+0.2*cos(\x)},{0.636+0.2*sin(\x)})  node[below=45]{femur Offset};
    \draw[ultra thick, dashed] (0.66,0.735) -- plot({0.66+0.38*cos(-80.63+41)},{0.735+0.38*sin(-80.63+41)}) -- (0.78,0.08);
    \draw[->,ultra thick,red,domain=-80.63:-39.63] -- plot({0.66+0.2*cos(\x)},{0.735+0.2*sin(\x)}) node[right=15] {tibia Offset};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: Drawing overlaying the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you like to obtain the following image:

[image]

you have two small errors in your code. in lines as

```
\draw[->,ultra thick,red,domain=22.84:37.84]  -- % <--- there is not starting coordinate
        plot({0.425+0.2*cos(\x)},{0.636+0.2*sin(\x)})  node[below=45]{femur Offset};
```

you not define starting coordinate. consequently `tikz` went to lost what it should draw. you only need to erase `--`:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}};%Medien/legdiagram.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    \draw[ultra thick, fill=black] (0.225,0.636) circle (5pt) node[above=35] {BC} -- (0.425,0.636) circle (5pt) node[below=20] {CF} -- (0.66,0.735) circle (5pt) node[above=20] {FT} -- (0.78,0.08) circle (5pt) node[below=5] {F};
    \draw[ultra thick, dashed]
        (0.425,0.636) --  plot({0.425+0.26*cos(15+22.84)},{0.636+0.26*sin(15+22.84)})
                      -- (0.66,0.735);
    \draw[->,ultra thick,red,domain=22.84:37.84]  % -- % <--- this -- should be erased
        plot({0.425+0.2*cos(\x)},{0.636+0.2*sin(\x)})  node[below=45]{femur Offset};
    \draw[ultra thick, dashed]
        (0.66,0.735) -- plot({0.66+0.38*cos(-80.63+41)},{0.735+0.38*sin(-80.63+41)})
                     -- (0.78,0.08);
    \draw[->,ultra thick,red,domain=-80.63:-39.63] % -- % <--- this -- should be erased
        plot({0.66+0.2*cos(\x)},{0.735+0.2*sin(\x)}) node[right=15] {tibia Offset};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```